# Is there any method for access the content in SDCARD

Tags: java, android, arrays, data-analysis, sonata-admin

I am currently working in sdcard detection in android studio in that I already access the directory of sdcard but I can't able to access the sdcard content it provide null exeception.

code line:

```
  File[] path = new File("/mnt/sdcard0").listFiles();
        sdFiles getFiles = new sdFiles(); //null pointer
```

Will you please give some code example for this issue

I tried like this:

```
          File[] path = new File("/mnt/sdcard0").listFiles();
          sdFiles getFiles = new sdFiles(); //null pointer
```

File did not listing the content

Comment: First, **never hardcode paths**. Beyond that, you have not had access to all of removable storage in years. Consider using `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` / `ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocumentTree` and letting the user decide what tree of documents to let your app access, whether that tree is on removable storage or elsewhere.

Comment: `new sdFiles()` cannot return a null pointer. Of course `new File("/mnt/sdcard0").listFiles();` may throw a `NullPointerException` if the specified path does not exist or you do not have the permission to access that path ...

Comment: Hi thank you for reply please give some idea for how to get permission to access that path

Comment: Hi please tell how to use  Action_open_Document_Tree